# Send HTML mail using Android intent

Tags: html, android, email, android-intent

I have generated an HTML code(complete with `<html><body></body></html>` tags) as a String. Now I want to send this HTML code as HTML to mail. My code is as below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"me@mydomain.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I would like to buy the following");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, purchaseOrder());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "sending mail"));
```

Where the `purchaseOrder()` is the method which passes me the string having full HTML code. But though the GMail client opens on my Nexus1 but it has the String with all HTML tags and not the actual HTML view. I tried the following but got error. The GMail crashed.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, purchaseOrder());
```

Comment: Since you can't format mail in the built-in mail application, this may not be possible with the Intent method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send HTML email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email)

Answer (score 27):

This works for me:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

But I've notice that inline styles and image tags are being ignored...

Comment: This worked for me as well, it's a bit touchy, but it worked from gmail anyway

Comment: This worked for me as well and it should be the correct answer to the question.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer body is just a string. `String body = "<h1>Test</h1>";`

Comment: This intent isn't strictly for sending e-mail. It's for sharing to an application that accepts data in HTML format. It just so happens to be that Gmail matches that constraint.

Comment: getting dialog as "No application can perform this action." one gmail client is installed.

Comment: Formatting is gone in yahoo mail app

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking to do this, sending the email manually behind the scenes using android-javamailer works (I've done it):

<s>[Sending Emails without User Intervention (no intents) in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)</s>

Comment: Yes but you can use your own business email and password to avoid needing the user's information to send an email

Comment: how is this secure? even if code is obfuscated i can still search for strings in code as well as inside strings.xml and find username and password.

Answer (score 1):

if i am not wrong what you were looking for was

```
   Html.fromHtml()
```

e.g.

```
Html.fromHtml("<a href="www.google.com"> Google</a>");
```

this will make Google a hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`  and my code goes here:

```
String mailId="yourmail@gmail.com";
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
                                    Uri.fromParts("mailto",mailId, null)); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject text here"); 
    // you can use simple text like this
    // emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Body text here"); 
    // or get fancy with HTML like this
    emailIntent.putExtra(
             Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
             Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
                 .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
             .append("<a>http://www.google.com</a>")
             .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
             .toString())
         );
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.email_subject));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.email_text)));
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "email"));
```

string.xml

```
<resources>    
<string name="email_subject">Download App for your smartphone.</string>
<string name="email_text"><![CDATA[Hey,<br/>I just downloaded App on my Android. 
<br/>It is a smartphone Manager.<br/>App is available for Android.<br/>
    Get it now from http://www.exampleapp.com/download]]></string>
```