# How to send email newsletter from android application programmatically

Tags: java, android, html, email

I am trying to send an HTML table through email, but what i only get is a string with the HTML code.
I read about email newsletter a little but i didn't figure out how to make it work in my android test application.

I have a regular table that insert into String string.

```
String string = "<table border='1' align='center'><tr style='color:blue'><th>Day</th><th>Date</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Total Time</th></tr><tr><td align='center'>Sunday</td><td align='center'>19/07/2011</td><td align='center'>13:00</td><td align='center'>19:00</td><td align='center'>06:00</td></tr></table>";    
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, getSenderList());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mContext.getText(R.string.app_name));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(string));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Someone can please point me how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: If you are sending emails through that Intent params like above, it will not work in emulator. That intent code works only on real device.

Comment: If you are sending emails through that Intent params like above, it will not work in emulator. That intent code works only on real device.

Comment: Thanks, but i already tried it in a real device and it also didn't work. It sends the mail but what i get on the other side is HTML code text.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following question:
[Send HTML mail using Android intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544141/android-send-html-mail-using-intent).

If you want to use the default mailer, change your code to the following:

```
    String body = "<table border='1' align='center'><tr style='color:blue'><th>Day</th><th>Date</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th><th>Total Time</th></tr><tr><td align='center'>Sunday</td><td align='center'>19/07/2011</td><td align='center'>13:00</td><td align='center'>19:00</td><td align='center'>06:00</td></tr></table>";

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + getSenderList()));
    intent.setType("text/html");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mContext.getText(R.string.app_name));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```