# Why isn't this code to send an HTML e-mail using an Intent working?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

Hi I am trying to send mail from my android application but I am not getting proper mail in my inbox
my code is here please help me.

```
Spanned mailBody2 = Html.fromHtml("<body><table width=\"200\" border=\"1\"><tr bgcolor=\"#3399FF\"><td>hi</td><td>gaurav</td><td>patel</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></body>");

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String[] recipients = new String[] { "jansodariya@gmail.com" };
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipients);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Summ");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mailBody2);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. You only can send text trough an email. You must use php to send formatted mails. Please read here also [Send HTML mail using Android intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544141/android-send-html-mail-using-intent)

Comment: Yes I tried this also but no different in result same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mailBody2);
```

to

```
String mailtext="<body><table width=\"200\" border=\"1\"><tr bgcolor=\"#3399FF\"><td>hi</td><td>gaurav</td><td>patel</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></body>";  

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(mailtext));
```

This should work. refer [this link](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/05/17/sending-html-email-with-android-intent/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you trying it on real device? and in gmail app (real device) or any other email client?