# Want my app to export data into html file

Tags: android

It's late and my brain can't even think of the proper things to search for to find the help I need.

Here's what I'm aiming for:

My app takes in a bunch of data from the user. Specifically sizes for windows and doors around a house. My app takes all that data and determines how much material is required, etc.

Here's where I'm stuck:

What I'd like to do is turn that all into a fancy looking report and offer the user the ability to print it. I figured the easiest way to do that would be to generate a report using HTML (or PDF) and have it open up in a web browser, which already has print capabilities.

Can anyone tell me if this seems like a good strategy for what I'm trying accomplish? And if so, point me in the right direction (or to the exact same questions that's already been answered somewhere on this forum).

Thanks.

Comment: Creating PDFs should be easier. Have a look at this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: You are doing it right, creating an HTML or PDF document will help in sending the document attached in Email. Once I had a similar problem, where I used HTML reports and sent to the server where they converted it into PDF and sent to the customer via email.

Comment: Sending email with html contents won't be a problem - Use intents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127676/how-to-send-html-mail-in-android OR just write your own mail engine: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and comments.