# How to use inline styles with android app email action?

Tags: android, css

I am trying to create an email from within a method with android that contains some style but it is not working, how can achieve this - or is it not possible?

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/html");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"test@example.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , Html.fromHtml("<p style='color: red'>Hello</p>"));

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            showWarning("There are no email clients installed");
        }
```

Comment: [tackoverflow.com/questions/2544141/send-html-mail-using-android-intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544141/send-html-mail-using-android-intent)

Comment: @MD I know how to send HTML, it is getting the CSS to be parsed that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

First, `Html.fromHtml()` does not handle `style` attributes. In this case, you can try `<font color="red">`, though I do not know if `fromHtml()` handles `red` or only supports hex color values. Or, you can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to color your text using a `ForegroundColorSpan`.

Second, you are delegating the email to a third-party app. Third-party apps do not necessarily have to support styling of the content. Hence, your red color may be dropped out by some email clients but not others.