# Email with HTML content is not working on Samsung native Email app

Tags: android, html, android-intent, email-client

I am using below code for sending the email.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "You are invited for a meeting");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(mailBody));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share meeting Info"));
```

*mailBody in EXTRA_TEXT is a HTML content with `<a>` tag and string message

Its working perfectly with Gmail app but anchor tag is not working in native email client in Samsung devices.

Comment: Change type to `text/html` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4394297/6254066

Comment: I checked it but didn't work for Samsung native email client.

Comment: Then either the Samsung native email client does not support HTML, or it is a Samsung bug

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code. It does not work in the stock email app, not just in Samsung devices. The stock email app needs to be updated, which is unlikely to happen at the same pace as the Gmail app.

Comment: For me its working in Gmail App even in Samsung device. But not working on Samsung native email.

Comment: The gmail app works in all devices. They just wont add good features to the stock email app for obvious reasons.