# how to send html email in android?

Tags: java, android, html, email, jakarta-mail

Hi I am making an app in which I am sending an email to a specific address

This email is a html email with table and images and all...[image: like this]

Is I have tried to add `Html.fromhtml()` but it keeps saying **type mismatch**
needed string found spanned....

If you need any of my code please comment

Please suggest any tutorial if you have in mind

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention I am sending mail using `javax.mail`library I am not using Intents
I tried to use `Html.tohtml(Spanned text)` its giving the message of type mismatch cant convert String to spannedtext

I have no idea whats happening

I am receiving the html data in my mail if i just go with it

**UPDATE**
I am fetching the content from a string resource
and this is what I am getting as result

> $message = ' For Support enquiry@makeintern.com￼Contact Form Enquiry !
>   Name: :'.$name.'Email: :'.$email.'Contact: :'.$mobile.'Message:
>   :'.$message.'Date-Time: :'.$current_date.'
>
> Thanks and Regards MakeIntern Team Account Manager - MakeIntern Cell
>   www.makeintern.com enquiry@makeintern.com
>
> If any query Please call us on : 011-45544188 ￼ www.makeintern.com |
>   enquiry@makeintern.com ￼￼￼￼

from---

```
<string name="email">$message = \'&lt;center&gt;
   &lt;table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"&gt;
   &lt;tr&gt;
  &lt;td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"&gt;
    &lt;table width="620px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"&gt;
    &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td width="400px"  bgcolor="#000000"  style="color:#FFFFFF; text-

decoration:none; float:left;font-size:10px;margin: -18px 3px -1px 11px; font-weight:bold; padding:2px; text-decoration:none; padding-left:0px;"&gt;For Support &lt;span style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;"&gt;enquiry@makeintern.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td width="220px" bgcolor="#000000"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;

&lt;tr style="background-color:#737373;"&gt;
&lt;td width="290" align="left" valign="middle"&gt;&lt;a href="http://makeintern.com" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.makeintern.com/images/makeintern.jpg" width="136" border="0" alt="MakeIntern" style="display:block; padding-left:0px;"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;td width="290" align="right" style="text-align:right; font-family:Arial, Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:18px; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:normal; padding-right:10px;"&gt;Contact Form Enquiry !&lt;br&gt;
&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
&lt;td height="12px" colspan="2"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
&lt;td colspan="2" align="center" style="line-height:16px; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; color:#888888; text-align:left;"&gt;
&lt;table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td width="200px" style="font-weight:bold;"&gt;Name: &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td width="100px"&gt;:&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;\'.$name.\'&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;

        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td width="200px" style="font-weight:bold;"&gt;Email: &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td width="100px"&gt;:&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;\'.$email.\'&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;

        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td width="200px" style="font-weight:bold;"&gt;Contact: &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td width="100px"&gt;:&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;\'.$mobile.\'&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;

        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td width="200px" style="font-weight:bold;"&gt;Message:  &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td width="100px"&gt;:&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;\'.$message.\'&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;

        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td width="200px" style="font-weight:bold;"&gt;Date-Time:  &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td width="100px"&gt;:&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;td&gt;\'.$current_date.\'&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;


        &lt;/table&gt;

        &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;

        Thanks and Regards &lt;br/&gt;
        MakeIntern Team &lt;br/&gt;
        Account Manager - MakeIntern Cell &lt;br/&gt;
        www.makeintern.com&lt;br/&gt;
        enquiry@makeintern.com&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;b&gt;If any query Please call us on : 011-45544188&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td height="12px"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;

        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td colspan="2"&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.myhotbooking.com/images/email-template/bar.png"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;

        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td colspan="2" bgcolor="#737373" height="90px"&gt;
        &lt;table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="620px"&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td height="10px"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;" height="20px"&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.makeintern.com/"&gt;www.makeintern.com &lt;/a&gt;| &lt;span style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;"&gt;enquiry@makeintern.com&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td align="center" valign="middle"&gt;
        &lt;a href="https://www.facebook.com/makeinterns" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.myhotbooking.com/images/email-template/icon-facebook.png" width="26" height="26" border="0" alt="Facebook"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="https://twitter.com/makeintern" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.myhotbooking.com/images/email-template/icon-twitter.png" width="26" height="26" border="0" alt="Twitter"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/makeintern" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.myhotbooking.com/images/email-template/icon-linkedin.png" width="26" height="26" border="0" alt="Linkedin"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="https://plus.google.com/+makeintern" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.myhotbooking.com/images/email-template/icon-google-plus.png" width="26" height="26" border="0" alt="Google+"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;


        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
        &lt;td align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF;"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;
        &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;
        &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;
        &lt;/center&gt;\'</string>
```

Thankyou in advance

Comment: What is your input in Html.fromhtml()? is it String?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544141/send-html-mail-using-android-intent

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
 sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.email_subject));
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.email_text)));
 sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
```

string.xml

```
<resources>    
    <string name="email_subject">Download App for your smartphone.</string>
    <string name="email_text"><![CDATA[Hey,<br/>I just downloaded App on my Android.<br/>It is a smartphone Manager.This app even lets me book parties,search restaurants.<br/>App is available for Android.<br/>
        Get it now from http://www.exampleapp.com/download]]></string>
</resources>
```