# Android Email intent ignoring line break ( "\n" or "<br/>" ?)

Tags: android, android-intent

Depending on which email app I used, the line break (does not) work:

1. possibility: using "\n" as a line break:

*In some E-Mail applications it works fine and in other apps it ignores them (so there is no wordwrap).*

2. possibility: using [image] as a line break:

*For the apps where the 1st option worked it shows some like that:*

[image]

*and in the E-Mail apps where the 1st option didn´t worked it works.*

**Does somebody know how i can solve the Probleme so the wordwrap works for every E-Mail App?**

Thanks!!

Comment: that depends on each individual app. if you use `<br/>` make sure to specify that the content type is html when firing the intent. But then other problems arise. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321168/sending-html-email-from-android-app-using-an-intent

Comment: TLDR: there's no way to guarantee how 3rd partys act. You could send your own emails: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60090464/413127

Comment: Email apps can send plain text or html mails.