# What apps consume Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing an app that needs to send an email with HTML.

I can't seem to find an app that will handle my intent *and* generate an HTML email with the value I provide to the extra `Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT`. I've tried with the apps I have on my phone (Gmail, Outlook) but both take the value provided to the extra `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` text instead.

Answer (score -1):

I've never met such apps. Maybe some custom ones. Try solution from [here](https://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/05/17/sending-html-email-with-android-intent/) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/4394297/2894819
(which is basically the same)

Comment: Thanks. I already have the intent built. I'm looking for a way to test and verify that it was built correctly. That's why I was hoping for an app that would consume my Intent.