# Triggering email from a specific email account in android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-manifest

Hi 
I am developing an android application in which a form has to be submitted over email.
my code is as follows

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"mail id"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subjec");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT  ,"Hi"
startActivity(i);
```

When I click submit on the form it is triggering a spinner from which user has to select email to goto email. The problem it is showing hell lot of other unnecessary options such as bluetooth, colornote etc...
I want only email or gmail to be shown or a better way it should directly goto email application

Please kindly give me your valuable advice.

Thanking you
Yours sincerely
Chinnikrishna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #1: Use `ACTION_SENDTO` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132889/action-sendto-for-sending-an-email) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/7bbf44396a67dd24).

Option #2: Use `message/rfc822` instead of `text/plain` (and format your message accordingly) as seen [here](http://snipt.net/Martin/android-intent-usage/).

Neither are guaranteed to only give you mail clients, though the first option is likely to only be mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
I found the answer to my question
I need to add

```
i.setType("application/octet-stream");
```

Then it is giving me only gmail and email :-)