# Intent type ACTION_SENDTO in Android. How does it work?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contacts

In my application I would like to send a message to someone (contact in phone) and I want user to decide which channel (SMS, e-mail, ...) he will use.

Documentation suggest that [ACTION_SENDTO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO) shall be used in this case. I'm using following code:

```
    private static void launchNewShareIntent(Context c, String subject, String text, String dialogTitle, Uri recipient) {
    Intent shareintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    shareintent.setData(recipient);        
    shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    shareintent.setType("text/plain");
    shareintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, dialogTitle));
}
```

where recipient is for example: `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/755`

However, the phone displays a dialog box with: "No applications can perform this action."

Has anybody succeeded with ACTION_SENDTO?

Comment: Are you testing this on a phone or an emulator ?

Comment: Both. And both gives me the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACTION_SENDTO does not appear to support a contact like you are using it, nor did I see anything in the documentation that implies that (to me, at least).  Passing a URI such as sms://2065551212, however, worked great for me.  Note, also, that ACTION_SENDTO does not support EXTRA_SUBJECT nor EXTRA_TEXT.  See [ACTION_SENDTO for sending an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132889/action-sendto-for-sending-an-email)

Thanks,
--randy

Comment: Well, thank you. 
It seems I misunderstood the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO). Apparently "someone specified by the data" is not a contact id, but phone number or e-mail address.