# Not able to compose a message in Motorola XT925 device

Tags: android, motorola

I am not able to compose a messge in Motorola XT925 device.

My code is as follows:

```
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "My message");
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(smsIntent);
```

The above code runs on all devices and shows the output "My messgae".But on Motorola XT925,it shows blank text.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem on Motorola Droid RAZR, Android 4.0.4. Maybe Motorola devices have custom sms client. Seems reasonable ask someone from their developer team.

**Updated:**
Finally I found solution for myself here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522616/1170154.

Comment: Can you pls tell me how you used that code snippet? Me too is stucked on that problem.