# Android not prompting me apps with email Capability

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a app, that takes information of some sort, then i want it to email that information to my gmail. I have found working code but when i load it onto my phone and run it  and got all the info loaded into the app,and click the email, from what i understand its suppose to filter apps(on my phone) that are capable to send the email but I'm not getting anything, even though i have the default Email app that comes on the phone and i have Gmail.

```
public void Done(View view) {
   Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // it's not ACTION_SEND
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "some@gmail.com");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "OverStock Changes");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, printReport());
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Email"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer for [ACTION_SENDTO for sending an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132889/action-sendto-for-sending-an-email)

> If you use ACTION_SENDTO, putExtra() does not work to add subject and
>   text to the intent. Use setData() and the Uri tool add subject and
>   text.
>
> This example works for me:

```
// ACTION_SENDTO filters for email apps (discard bluetooth and others)
String uriText =
    "mailto:youremail@gmail.com" + 
    "?subject=" + URLEncoder.encode("some subject text here") + 
    "&body=" + URLEncoder.encode("some text here");

Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email"));
```

Otherwise use `ACTION_SEND` as mentioned:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mail@mail.com","mail2@mail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail content");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title of dialog"));
```

Comment: adding subjecct/text isnt my problem, its startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email")); thats suppose to give me apps that have email cababilities but im not getting any says none were found

Comment: I don't see a setData in your code, ACTION_SENDTO uses data instead of Extras. Try adding the uri since it might be related to it missing. Don't forget the crucial part `mailto:`