# Check if elements in a check list are ticked and send those via email?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

```
Intent next = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
next.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:zuron7@gmail.com"));
next.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attendance");
String message = "";
Resources r = getResources();
String name = getPackageName();
int[] ids = new int[3];
for(int i =0; i<3;i++){
    String x = "check"+i;
    ids[i]= r.getIdentifier(x,"id", name);
}
for(int i = 0; i<3;i++){
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(ids[i]);
    if(checkbox.isChecked()){
        message=message+getResources().getString(R.string.Swag1);
    }
}
next.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
if (next.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
    startActivity(next);
```

When I run the app on my phone and hit the button which launches this method, it stops unexpectedly. I'm not really sure where the problem is. I basically want to take attendance for a group of students and send the names of those absent to the coordinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will solve your problem: [ACTION_SENDTO for sending an email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522616/1279562)

Basically you should try to pass your subject and message via the URI in setData.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the solution in one of the Android guides too.