# Android mail client popup in app?

Tags: android, email, client

Is there a way to have the default mail client pop up with a pre filled email?  An in app popup would be best, but I suppose a redirect to the mail app would also work.

This is the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5522616/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare That post did it - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!