# How Send Email with Html Content and image in Android

Tags: android, html, email

I want to send an email from my android application which  have  HTML content and also an image as attachment.My searching results revealed that it is not possible to send an image using  tag of HTML.How can i achieve this?.ie, I want **content in HTML**(These are some URLs) and send an **image as attachment**.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you [done any research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email)?

Answer (score 2):

```
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp,"title", null);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent
        .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddresses);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
emailIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using"));
```

Its usefull to Send mail