# send emailwith html content and image with android

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I want to send an email from my android application which have HTML content and also an image.
I have tried this code

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mailIntent.setType("text/html");
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.subject_mail));
        mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

But i have always an icon "obj" instead of image

Comment: Hopefully this stackoverflow answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745702/814353

Comment: but the problem when display a picture not diplayinf text