# Email body content not coming in bold

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I need some portion of my email body to be in bold. I tried many solutions but didn't get the result. Can anyone point out what went wrong in my code?

```
String body = "<html><body><b>" + getName() + "</b></body></html>";
String myURL =  "http://www.google.com"

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setType("text/plain")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, context.getString(R.string.email_subject, getName()))
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {context.getString(R.string.email_address)})
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new StringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(body))
            .append("\n")
            .append(myURL);

return Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried setType("text/html")

Comment: Here you have solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email

Comment: @aegean I saw that we can't use "text/html" if you are using EXTRA_TEXT (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)

Comment: Is it working if you try putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body)); (without appending \n and myUrl)?

Comment: @aegean yes…this is working..but if I append its not…what may be the reason for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send HTML email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email)

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this.

```
String tempString= getName.toString();
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Mathew, try this solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: What do you have in getName().

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>"+YOUR STRING+Html.fromHtml("</b>"));
```