# android email intent with hyperlink

Tags: android, email, android-intent, hyperlink

Trying to add hyperlink with email intent, but on other side i got nothing just plain text. If i use gmail client application, this works great but not with default email app(device inbuid app).

here is my code snipt

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
 emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gyc.com","aaa@bbb.com"});
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check this out!");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"www.google.com\">link</a>"));
 startActivityForResult(emailIntent,Util.EMAILREQUESTCODE);
```

[please check this screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/YGJDjF9qrYb)

Answer (score 0):

Set the type as "text/html" i.e. `emailIntent.setType("text/html");`

Comment: if i use gmail application to send email, this works perfectly. but if i use default email app, it send email as plain text

Comment: do you know something about this question @vorrtex?

Comment: @HashirSheikh Such question was already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email, you probably should use `ACTION_SENDTO` instead of `ACTION_SEND`

Comment: @vorrtex this not working for me, but this reduce application in intent chooser, now only email supported application is visible in intent chooser.

Comment: i think 'it works with gmail,the standard Android Mail app just drops the HTML formatting including links'

Comment: @HashirSheikh Does it work for bold/italic tags? What happens if you send to the intent a plain text without calling `fromHtml`?

Comment: @vorrtex, if i send only plain text message is show up like this "<a href=\"www.google.com\">link</a>",

The link you mention here is give same result as my code except application filter (now only email client application is visible :) ), But not solve my problem :(