# Android Default EMAIL client not sending HTML content

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send email with HTML content by intent. HTML content includes anchor tag. It is working fine when i send the email by G-MAIL but when i send it by default email client than the anchor tag is sent as plain text. I have googled a lot but not found an answer. Many have written its an android email client bug.

Code i have written is

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 

emailIntent.setType("text/html"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subjectEncoded); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , Html.fromHtml(body));
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

where body is

```
<a href='http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf'>PDF URL</a>
```

Comment: @LarsBlumberg Thanks but I have already tested the link you provided. But it dint worked.

Comment: answer at [How to send HTML email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email) is not the correct answer for this question.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson please stop marking these quesitons as duplicate. The "original" question has no valid answer.