# How to send HTML mail using Android intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

```
final Intent shareIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```

Even I have pasted this code from a solved question([How to send HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email)). Still not working in my case.

Comment: It's working fine!

Comment: if you send intent to gmail app, it will go to editing page before sending it. And as far i know, edit text in gmail app doesnt support html tag.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira It's working fine with Gmail too!

Comment: Html can be use in email.. you just missing one thing..add this`shareIntent.setType("message/rfc822");`

Comment: @android_griezmann its working fine if you send it through smtp within your app, not gmail app

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I am using the gmail itself [look at this link](https://s30.postimg.org/qp1kjqp0x/device_2016_12_27_121029.png)

Comment: @MuhammadHafiqIqmal: I have added this "shareIntent.setType("message/rfc822")" above shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");. But now it's not popping up any email app. Just showing a message "No apps can perform this action."

Comment: @android_griezmann i cant make it. https://s28.postimg.org/6j74jbnq5/Screenshot_2016_12_27_13_47_25.png

Comment: use SEND instead of SENDTO... SENDTO putextra is not working..

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I guess you have directly passed the html content like this shareIntent.putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "<p><b>Some Content</b></p>");  You should passed it just like the way in the question.

Comment: @ZeroOne Replaced SENDTO with SEND. Now showing email apps. But stil the output is same. [see the link for output](https://s24.postimg.org/4o8ol57ph/Screenshot_20161227_140051.png)

Comment: I confirm the same output as the link by @Jeet on multiple devices. Has this been confirmed to be a regression in the Gmail app, as suggested by the answer below?

Comment: @android_griezmann please give snippet for this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a regression in the GMail app. It was working fine before and now it's not working anymore. It might be a bug or it might have been disabled on purpose for security reasons...
Anyway I don't think you'll be able to fix this on your side