# Has Android's Gmail app removed the ability to send HTML emails via Intent?

Tags: android, html, android-intent, gmail

I would like to send HTML emails via an Intent. It seems that the accepted way to do this is as follows:

```
String body = "I am <b>bold text</b> and I am <i>italic text</i> and I am normal text.";

final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

This does not work in Gmail v6.11.2 and 7.1.129 and produces plain text output. The only tags I see recognized are `<p>` and `<br>`.

My email must be editable by the user, so sending it in background via JavaMail API is not an option.

I have also attempted: `emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");`

and: `emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, "Hello I am <b>bold</b> text.");`

If this was once working, can someone confirm that this is a regression in the Gmail app's functionality as suggested by this user: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41596827/1319081, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
String body = new String("<html><body><table><tr><td><br/>" +header+"</td></tr><br/><br/>"+"Get <b> Best Score </b> in your Android Phone.<br/>"+"<a href=\"" + link_val + "\">" + text_value+ "</a>");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, html.fromHtml(body));
```

Android support only some Tag..
For more information check below link..

[Link 1](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)

[Link 2](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Comment: This produces the same result: plain text in the Gmail editor with all formatting tags removed, which is why I assume it is a Gmail issue or regression.

Comment: i have editted my answer, please check it. Android support few tags of html.

Comment: Once again, all tags are removed and the output is plain text.

Comment: have you checked the link?

Comment: Yes, it appears Gmail has removed this functionality. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code itself.