# Send email body as html text

Tags: android, html, email, xamarin

I am trying to send an email from my Android app

```
public void SubmitInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            StringBuilder htmlBodyMail = new StringBuilder();
            htmlBodyMail.AppendLine("Hello from XYZ Application!" + "\n\n" +
                "<b>Address:</b> " + App.Address + "\n\n" +
                "<b>DataTime:</b> " + App.DataTime + "\n\n" +
                "<b>GPS:</b> " + App.Latitude + ", " + App.Longitude);

            var emailTask = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
            if (emailTask.CanSendEmail)
            {
                var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
                .To("xxx@xxx.com")
               .Subject("XYZ Application")
               .BodyAsHtml(htmlBodyMail.ToString())
               .WithAttachment(App._file.AbsoluteFile)
               .Build();
                emailTask.SendEmail(email);
            }   
     }
```

However when I receive the message in the email, there are no Bolds or end of Lines as coded into the html string. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you checking CanSendEmailBodyAsHtml?

Comment: have you tried replacing `\n` with `<br>` and `<b>` with `<strong>`?

Answer (score 0):

I have test in in native Android, it's the same effect. As [user1026605](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340015/how-to-send-html-mail-using-android-intent/41596827#41596827) said, it was working fine before but now it's not working anymore. I think google has been disabled on purpose for security reasons too.